# PHP classes: abstract, traits, extend, interface, singletons

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, extending

I had a very long "Playlist" class; having functions that, among others, would handle the playlist cache, variables, and presets.

```
class Playlist{

    var $cache;
    var $variables;
    var $preset;

    function __construct(){
        $this->cache = populate_cache();
        $this->variables = $this->populate_variables();
        $this->preset = $this->populate_preset();
    }
    function populate_cache(){
    }
    function populate_variables(){
    }
    function populate_preset(){
    }
}
```

As it was becoming very difficult to read (lots of function for stuff related to cache, variables, presets), I started to split that into several classes (code is reduced here):

```
class Playlist{

    var $cache;
    var $variables;
    var $presets;

    function __construct(){
        $this->cache = new PlaylistCache($this);
        $this->variables = new PlaylistVariables($this);
        $this->presets = new PlaylistPreset($this);
    }
}

class PlaylistCache{
    var $playlist;
    function __construct(&$playlist){
        $this->playlist = $playlist;
    }
}

class PlaylistVariables{
    var $playlist;
    function __construct(&$playlist){
        $this->playlist = $playlist;
    }
}

class PlaylistPreset{
    var $playlist;
    function __construct(&$playlist){
        $this->playlist = $playlist;
    }
}
```

So the Playlist object is passed to every "subclass".  If I well understood, this is called [Dependency Injection](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-in-php--net-28146).  I'm not sure this is very smart since

- It seems to me quite a weird way of coding.
- It produces recursions in my code, eg. the playlist object is passed to the PlaylistCache class; but the PlaylistCache IS defined in the playlist object, which makes ... a nasty loop.  If I print_r my Playlist object, i'll see *RECURSION* written in the code.

BUT I need to be able to access the whole Playlist object through every subclass, and that's the only way I found for the moment.

I already know about [extending classes](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php), but I don't want to extend my class here : cache, variables and presets are not a different kind of Playlist, they are "properties" that my Playlist needs to populate.

I dug a little and read about [Abstract Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php), [Traits](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.traits.php), [Interfaces](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.interfaces.php), and i guess my solution is somewhere in that.  But I can't find where and it's quite difficult for me to understand since it's really abstract and english is not my first language.

So : does anyone see what I mean and have suggestions ?
Thanks !

Comment: What you are doing is not dependency injection, just regular parent/child relationships. And the recursion is not a bad thing at all, it just illustrates the underlying mutual dependency. So all in all, not much wrong with your code right now apart from all the `&`'s in the constructors.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, it is by no means a *parent/child relationships*. It is a composition.

Comment: And composition is one of (many) ways to express a functional parent/child relationship. DI on the other hand is not about hierarchical relationships but about the separation of concerns. The linked article about DI is bullshit, and written by a narcissistic idiot.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the comments are misleading. The "child" classes use Dependency Injection and not an Inheritance parent/child relationship. The playlist (parent) class does use composition, however.

The &'s in the constructors constitute '[passing by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)'. To pass by value, the class would need [accessor methods](http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/php-oop-accessor-destructor). If you only ever want one instance of say... the current playlist, a [singleton](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html#Singleton) makes sense. [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) are a copy paste solution - the design for a singleton pattern could be housed in a trait, but the use of a singleton would not be.

Consider what the playlist* classes actually need from the Playlist and consider passing those values explicitly.